# Append based on condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df1` with columns `ID2, Name2, ID3, Name3`. I have other two data frame `df2` (columns: `Name2, ID2`) and `df3` (columns: `Name3, ID3`) with the same columns. I am trying to merge `df2` and `df3` based on matching ID, which I do as follows:

```
Solution = pd.merge(df2,df3, left_on='ID2',right_on='ID3').sort_values('Name2')
```

Now I want to append this result to `df1`, only if ID2/ID3 doesn't already exist in `df1`. How do I do that?

Comment: Append then [drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates)???

Comment: I want to check it before I append.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isin`:

```
df1.append(Solution[~Solution['ID2'].isin(df1['ID1'])])
```

Comment: Thank you. Great solution. Add a ')' at the end. It's missing!

Comment: @piRSquared Is there a way to append after we check if the pair of Name and ID is present instead of just ID?

Comment: @Boud Is there a way to append after we check if the pair of Name and ID is present instead of just ID?